# use or replace table rows[rowID] javascript function for Div

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to replace my old method of using `table` with div and which I'm accomplishing successfully but I'm stuck in a problem. The situation is that in my table method I'm hiding some of my `<tr style="display:none;">` which are not required by using some java-script functions and display when it is required.
Now I'm converting my tables rows and column by div and the method which I'm using to show only works for table.When the `.php` page is open I'm passing arguments in url for example `localhost/royaltrade/user_access.php?rptType=UserLog` and getting it by using `$_REQUEST['rptType']` method after this `<body onload="funControls();">` calling function which use that case and switch to a function called `funControls()` and select the case and execute its line.How Can I hide and show my div ? ?? ?

Here is my javascript code

```
 function funControls()
 {
 <?
 switch($_REQUEST['rptType'])
  {


        case 'UserLog':
            echo "showRows('table','CompName');";
            echo "showRows('table','UserName');";
            echo "showRows('table','StartingDate');";   
            echo "showRows('table','EndingDate');";
            $title='User Log';
            $path="browser_reports/rptUserLog.php";
            $selected='UserLog';             
            break;
     }
  ?>

  }
```

Here is the problem in that function can't use rows[rowId] Function for div

```
 function showRows(tableId,rowId){
 var hide= true;
 var t = document.getElementById(tableId);
 var rowStyle = (hide)? "block":"";
 t.rows[rowId].style.display = rowStyle;
 }
 function hideRows(tableId,rowId){
 var hide= true;
 var t = document.getElementById(tableId);
 var rowStyle = (hide)? "none":"";
 t.rows[rowId].style.display = rowStyle;
 }
```

Here is my body tag which calls the function onload

```
 <body onLoad="funControls();" >
```

Here is my HTML working

```
  <table  id="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center"> 
   <tr height="35" id="CompName" style="display:none">
    <td width="150">Select Company:</td>                                                                        
    <td width="200">                                                         
    <select class="textbox" name="cboCompName" style="width:178px" id ="cboCompName">

  <option value="-1"> Select </option>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 </table>
```

Here is the **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/8/)** working with table

Here is the **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/10/)** working with div in which I want to acheive this methodology

Comment: `showRows` is only toggling the visibility via `display` property, is the markup already created and rendered?

Comment: i didn't get you markup means ? ?  it will show tha row on the basis of case if it is equal to the case than it will show the rows

Comment: But is the html markup already created? And how does it look like?

Comment: how i'll show you the html working

Comment: Create a working snippet using `<>` of the rendered code (not your php) including JS and html.

Comment: ok wait !! i Will post it and now look at the edited answer

Comment: do you have any idea how to show div ?? like this methodology @gurvinder372

Comment: div will be shown or hidden the same way, but I don't see any div in your markup.

Comment: but it is not working with row function i don't know why

Comment: ok with my code can you show me a div hide and show on call ???

Comment: Almost impossible to tell why unless you can share a working snippet which demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Here is js filddle link but not working giving error [js](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/7/)

Comment: You need to remove the php code from it and only give the rendered value.

Comment: @gurvinder372 ok here is the working <b>[JD Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/8/)</b> know I want to apply this on div

Comment: @gurvinder372 here is the [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/10/) working where table replace by div

Comment: I will take a look at it and let you know.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `showRows` function to

```
function showRows( rowId )
{
    document.getElementById(rowId).style.display = "block";
}
```

Since you are already passing the `rowId`, no need to pass the `tableId` as well since ids are unique in the entire page.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er3wb896/11/) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you that is what I want Now I'll apply this on my code than i'll further tell you about my progress

Comment: hehehehe Thanks (: